# Solution for sets of $(x_k-x_l)(x_l-x_m)(x_m-x_k)>0$

Tags: inequality, graph-theory, systems-of-equations

Given a set of inequalities like the following:
$$
(x_k-x_l)(x_l-x_m)(x_m-x_k)>0, 
$$
with $x_n\in\mathbb N_0$. These inequalities have solutions, when $\{x_k,x_l,x_m\}$ obeys a cyclic ordering like $\{0,1,2\}$, e.g. $(0-1)(1-2)(2-0)=2>0$.

How to show that a given set of inequalities has or does not have a solution?

This is easy when all inequalities have independant variables. How entangled can these systems get before it gets impossible to solve them?

**EDIT**: The question is in fact graph theorectically motivated: How to colour the edges of a $3$-regular simple graph (e.g. below) so that the colours of the edges that meet at a point always obey a cyclic clockwise ordering?

$\hskip1.5in$[image]

Comment: $$x_{l}=x_{k}+d_{1};$$
$$x_{m}=x_{k}+d_{2};$$
$$d_{1}d_{2}^{2}>d_{1}^{2}d_{2};$$

Comment: From unsolvability of [Hilbert's tenth problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_tenth_problem) it follows that it is undecidable whether a general inequality has a solution in $\Bbb N$.

Comment: @draks Your rebel attack is awesome :)

Comment: @Wojowu my inequalities aren't that general (see my added motivation) and if you could give an answer if $x_n\in\mathbb R$, it'll be also cool...

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice you mentioned that the inequalities are supposed to be of the specified form. However, I don't see how one could encode cyclicity like this for more than three numbers. Either way, existence of solutions of inequalities in $\Bbb R$ is (in principle) decidable thanks to general result about decidability of theory of real closed fields, but I don't know if that's of help for you.

Answer (score 2):

**The graph-theoretical problem** for cube can be simplified by taking the quotient of cube by a symmetry subgroup that

- preserves the orientation of cube's surface,
- does not identify edges starting in any vertex.

Then you change equivalent numbers a bit and get a solution.

**For example,** first take a symmetry around the center of cube, see the left image for the quotient space, then take a rotation in the plane of the monitor by $180°$, see the right one.

[image: Left/right -- a quotient of the cube taken once/twice]

Comment: +1 Interesting, but the cube was just an example I had at hand. I replaced 'cubic' by 3-regular. Is it possible to extend your approach?

Comment: @draks, 3-regular with cyclic orderings at vertices? An obvious counterexample: two vertices with three parallel edges, but ordered differently at vertices.

Comment: Okay I also forgot simple...